# Spring Security and CAS. Anonymous User after success authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cas

I try configure Spring Security for working with CAS. I am on step when I got success authentication, CAS give ticket for my application. 
But after success authentication in CAS I need take user name and sent request to another system, but I don't know how because here

```
SecurityContext ctx=SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = ctx.getAuthentication();
```

I see that I have anonymous user.
I don't have to much time for that so I need your help, I repet my problem.

In which place after authentication I can find user name and send request to another system?
I do CAS client according to [this tuturial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate).

Edited: 
I am adding my cobfiguration code, should be easier:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
private SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter;
private LogoutFilter logoutFilter;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider,
                      AuthenticationEntryPoint eP,
                      LogoutFilter lF
        , SingleSignOutFilter ssF
) {
    this.authenticationProvider = casAuthenticationProvider;
    this.authenticationEntryPoint = eP;

    this.logoutFilter = lF;
    this.singleSignOutFilter = ssF;

}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return new CCDUserDetailsService();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(ServiceProperties sP) throws Exception {
    CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setServiceProperties(sP);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    return filter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .regexMatchers("/secured", "/login")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(logoutFilter, LogoutFilter.class);
}

}
```

And here I have configuration for CAS Provider.

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationApp {

@Value("${serviceProperties.protocol}")
String serviceProperiesProtocol;

@Value("${serviceProperties.host}")
String serviceProperiesHost;

@Value("${serviceProperties.port}")
String serviceProperiesPort;

@Value("${entryPoint.protocol}")
String entryPointProtocol;

@Value("${entryPoint.host}")
String entryPointHost;

@Value("${entryPoint.port}")
String entryPointPort;

@Autowired
CCDUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
    serviceProperties.setService("https://localhost:8080");
    serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
    return serviceProperties;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(
        ServiceProperties sP) {

    CasAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint
            = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setLoginUrl(entryPointProtocol + "://" +
            entryPointHost + ":" + entryPointPort + "/cas/login");
    entryPoint.setServiceProperties(sP);
    return entryPoint;
}

@Bean
public TicketValidator ticketValidator() {
    return new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator(
            entryPointProtocol + "://" +
                    entryPointHost + ":" + entryPointPort + "/cas");
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {

    CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    provider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setKey("CAS_PROVIDER_LOCALHOST_9000");
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler() {
    return new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
}

@Bean
public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(
            entryPointProtocol + "://" +
                    entryPointHost + ":" + entryPointPort + "/cas/logout",
            securityContextLogoutHandler());
    logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout/cas");
    return logoutFilter;
}

@Bean
public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix(entryPointProtocol + "://" +
            entryPointHost + ":" + entryPointPort + "/cas");
    singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
    return singleSignOutFilter;
}

@EventListener
public SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener singleSignOutHttpSessionListener(
        HttpSessionEvent event) {
    return new SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener();
}

}
```

[image: CAS console log]

[image: URL after login]

I want confirm also that if I have situation like on the above images, I have success full authentication from CAS side.

**But where I can find information about user login or this ticked from url?**

Answer (score 1):

If you followed this tutorial, do you by any chance have this in your configuration?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .permitAll();
}
```

Specifically the `permitAll` statement, which would disable all authentication mechanism in your code. You probably want to have `fullyAuthenticated` instead

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .fullyAuthenticated();
}
```

Two things that pop up are:

Consider not making `CasAuthenticationFilter` a bean, and insert it manually at the position you want it.

Then ensure that after your filter has been called, the filter or the authentication manager called

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(yourAuthenticationObjectHere);
```